# Steam Produced by Induction Cookers

Tags: thermodynamics, water, evaporation, liquid-state

I had recently noticed that induction cookers produce much more steam than normal gas tops and when I set the setting in the induction cooker to 'steam' it produces ever more steam. I used the same vessel, covered it and opened to check it after the same time interval. I am curious about the reason behind this.

I also noticed that when I set the induction cooker to 'steam' setting the water heated up to a lower temperature along with producing a lot of water vapor.

I will conduct the same experiment once again and share proper results.

Answer (score 2):

Note you can't see steam.  What you are seeing above the pan is the condensation of some of the vapor from the pan.  This depends both on the vapor from the pan as well as the surrounding conditions.

An induction cooker probably doesn't produce much heat outside the vessel.  While a gas cooker will heat the air below the pan and will probably produce some convection of warm air around the pan.

It is very possible that the condensation of vapor from the pan is reduced when there are warm air currents than when it is in otherwise still air.

I have no idea what kind of device you are referring to that has a "steam" setting.  If it is relevant, you should probably describe it in greater detail.

I would assume the amount of actual steam produced to depend heavily on the power delivered to the vessel.  And there's no reason to assume that is the same across different cooking devices.  Presumably they should be similar so that cooks aren't completely thrown by the differences of "high" from one device to another, but that doesn't mean they're close enough for your purposes.

Comment: I was talking about a button with the word 'steam' written on top of it. What makes it weird is that in the normal 'hotpot' and 'steam' settings 2kW of power is used but the amount of steam produced is greater in 'steam' setting. If you were referring to the water droplets on the lid of the vessel as condensation that isn't what I was talking about.

https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-758689197cba3904325e47a0a82d4d5a

This is what I meant as steam, correct me if this is not really steam and is condensation visible to us.

Comment: I am probably misinformed and the thing show in the image is not really steam as steam (water vapor) is not visible. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What the button does depends on the device.  I have no idea what device you have or what the button does.  But probably all it does is change the power delivered to the induction surface.  How do you measure that both buttons use the same power?

Comment: The power is displayed, I too am not really sure what the button does differently.